# Youtube Data Api - How to get a list of subscribed shows?

Tags: youtube-api, show, youtube-javascript-api

So how do I get a list of shows that authorized user has subscribed to?

For example I have subscribed to http://www.youtube.com/show/nationalgeographiclive but I don't get this show in my subscriptions list when I call subscriptions.list in api v3.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug filed against YouTube for this issue.

https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=4605